# Problem in calculating time complexity for the given code

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the given code?
answer: O(log2n)
how? (i=0;i<n;i*2) it's loops infinite until when the condition meets false

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIoJa.png)

Comment: I guess it should be `i=i*2` instead of just `i*2`.

Comment: Indeed, `i` should start at 1, not 0.

Comment: @Olivier I thought the same but even if i = 0, it loops infinite, I think it is a printing mistake or I miss something. resources: code from the book - javascript data structures and algorithms    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SgLBjXqwd4&list=PLDN4rrl48XKpZkf03iYFl-O29szjTrs_O&index=7 and  https://twitter.com/satyasridevisk/status/1429430521046568960?s=20

Comment: It's better if you insert the code into the question as text and not as a link to an image. Images can be deleted and links can become broken.

Comment: Actually I tried insert code . Editing problem. I can't post the question

Answer (score 0):

You have infinite loop cause you simply multiply a zero value in your incremental expression, without set a new value in the variable `i`.

Because of this, the condition you set is therefore valid at all times.

You need to really increment your `i` to break the loop.

For example, your incremental expression should be like this :

```
i *= 2
```

instead of

```
i * 2
```

If you really want your variable `i` to be 0 at initialization while keeping your algorithm as is, then you must increment it in your `for` scope loop to avoid having an infinite loop.